# Should I be able to get my user's Facebook adgroups with a general_user role for the adaccount

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

My web app authenticates the user and retrieves her advertising accounts with her user token:

```
/me?fields=id,name,adaccounts
```

After I received the ad account ids I am trying retrieve the adgroups for one of them:

```
/act_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/adgroups
```

but I am getting an error:

```
(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action'
```

My user has a `GENERAL_USER` role for this ad account. **Is this user role sufficient for this API call?** I cannot seem to find this in the official documentation. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which access level do you have for the API? If development, there's an open bug where the true error message for some cases ("user X is not an admin on account Y" or "account X is not listed in the Ads API part of the app settings for account Y") is not returned and you get that error #10 instead

Comment: The webapp's access level is 'Development' as it is before any Facebook approvals. The user (who has the 'general_user' role for the queried ad account) had been added as a tester to this webapp, to make it work. I have also added the user's advertising account to the Ads API part of the webapp's settings.

Comment: The user's attributes for the queried ad account are: "role": 1002,  "permissions": [2, 3, 4,  7]  I am not sure what the next steps should be to debug this further. I would greatly appreciate any help to get me out of this hole I am in, thanks!

Comment: have you specified the ad accounts to use within the app's settings? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985300/facebook-ads-api-error-not-enabled-for-usage/26996016#26996016

Comment: The user needs to be an **admin** of the account and of the app if the app is in the 'development' access level of the API - tester is not sufficient, this is different to how other permissions work and is specific to the ads API

Comment: Thanks Igy. It seems that, this was it. The person with the Facebook account was only an advertiser for the queried ad account and not an admin, whilst we only have 'development' access level. I've submitted now for basic access.