# error occured when setup and use facebook ads api in php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Fatal error: Uncaught exception

`FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action`

Comment: Please check following link might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604001/facebook-ads-api-10-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-perform-this-a

Comment: have you requested the ads_management permission? Have you listed yor ad account under the settings?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985300/facebook-ads-api-error-not-enabled-for-usage/26996016#26996016

Comment: yes we also have request for ads_management permission.